# What is the standard way to package a package before uploading to PyPi?

Tags: python, package

What is the standard, common way to package a Python package before uploading it to PyPi? (Be it a library for other programmers or an executable Python application).

I know about distutils. But it this the standard way I should learn and use? Or are there other approaches?

EDIT: I understand there might be many options. If so, please review and compare them so I know what to use.

Comment: Hahahahahahaha there are so many things. Good luck!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is there a reason why you are not considering PyPi?

Comment: @eandersson I edited the question to clarify. I meant I know about PyPI, but I'm talking about the stage before uploading to PyPi.

Comment: Depends on the target system. For Debian based distros, a .deb package is standard, for RedHat based distros .rpm etc. PyPI is a system independent python based package manager, so maybe you would want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

[PyPI - the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) would be the standard way of distributing python packages, and you have a pretty comprehensive guide on how to package and distribute your application [here](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/).

There is really only one way to package a Python application or library for PyPI, which would be through [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), but there are some additional tools you can use to package your projects. An example is [pbr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbr); which was created for the Openstack project can be used to simplify the process.

Finally as mentioned in the comments you could also package your project using a platform specific tool; such as an RPM for Linux or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for Windows, but I would only recommend this if you are targeting a very specific platform.